# XLSX Writer - Saving Tables as Picture Files - Python

Tags: python, powerpoint, xlsxwriter, presentation

This is a bit of a conceptual problem and I have to believe others have the same issue.

We use XLSXWriter to create very heavily formatted tables using Excel - we use fonts, data bars, conditional formatting, etc.  In short, we use XLSX writer to create presentation quality output.  We create a dozen or so charts at a clip for a given presentation in one worksheet.

Unfortunately, Excel isn't a presentation tool, so we need to get those formatted tables out of Excel and into (initially) Powerpoint.

Is there a way to select a range and save it as a picture using XLSXWriter?  If not, is there a way to do this using another methodology (loop through the individual tables, save them as picture files)?

If there a way to select a range using XLSXWriter, copy it to the clipboard and then save it using something like

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
im = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
im.save('somefile.png','PNG')
```

We considered using save as HTML, but that results in a loss of formatting

Sorry for the purely conceptual question, but I am at a loss as to where to go.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: *Is there a way to select a range and save it as a picture using XLSXWriter?* In relation to this part of the question the answer is no. XlsxWriter only creates an xlsx file. It doesn't have anyway of interacting with Excel and the file itself doesn't have any images. The best, and probably only, way to do what you want is to automate Excel to save to PDF or save a range as an image. Or use some other tool that takes screenshots of Excel.

Comment: I didn't think so, but figured I'd ask.. I guess the question is is there an alternate way to access the file once written and do the same thing?  Perhaps using something like win32com.. thx